# Driving a BLDC motor, having three switches on at the same time

Tags: mosfet, inverter, brushless-dc-motor, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I am currently working on a 14p BLDC motor and I wanted to drive it using 180 degree commutation (having 3 switches on at the time instead of 2). How can this be achieved? how can I know the correct switching patterns?

Comment: What has your web searching told you?  Can you share pages that tell how to do it, or ones that seem to come close?

Comment: There is not much information on the Web about this

Comment: Where did you hear about it, then?  If it were common, I promise you you'd be under a pile of answers by now.

Comment: There is small amount of information I saw in one paper but not enough, also it makes sense to do it as long as the same sides of the bridge are not on at the same time.